# Storing user details in application variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to store some 100 users details (username) in Application variable?I know how to use session but i dont know how to use Application variable and how to store in global.asax file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using of Application is absolutely like using Session. But this value are shared for all users.

**Update**
in global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var userList = new List<string>();
    Application["UserList"] = userList;
}
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var userName = Membership.GetUser().UserName;

    List<string> userList;
    if(Application["UserList"]!=null)
    {
        userList = (List<string>)Application["UserList"];
    }
    else
        userList = new List<string>();
    userList.Add(userName);
    Application["UserList"] = userList;
}
```

Comment: But where can i store the details of the users?in global.asax file?how to know which user is logged in at the moment?

Answer (score 3):

```
var users = new List<string>(){
    "mary", "bob"
};
HttpContext.Current.Application["users"] = users;
```

Comment: Can i store the details in global.asax file to use the details globally?

Comment: How to know which user is logged in at the moment?how can we retrieve the user details?

Comment: @Chandrasekhar Have a look at the Membership API