# How to create a global list variable in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want, in my WPF app, to store all my log in a list variable.

I have two pages, Home.xaml and Settings.xaml.

How can I access the same variable in the two pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a truly global variable then you can use a `static`

```
static class Container {
  public static List<string> LogList = new List<string>();
}
```

Any page can now access this value with `Container.LogList`

Comment: I don't want it to be truly global, but to be accessed from any page. Is it the best and most efficient way?

Comment: @ApocKalipsS in order to be accessed from both pages you either need to pass the instance of the list to both pages or make the value static.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really know what to choose: @Balaji solution (built-in functionality but needs a cast) or yours?

Comment: Where do you define and call this ?

Answer (score 2):

The Application class already has this functionality built in.

```
    // Set an application-scope resource
Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationScopeResource"] = Brushes.White;
...
// Get an application-scope resource
Brush whiteBrush = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationScopeResource"
```

Also check these links for more info

[Storing user details in application variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888603/storing-user-details-in-application-variable)

[How can I save global application variables in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910421/how-can-i-save-global-application-variables-in-wpf)

[WPF Application using a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161459/wpf-application-using-a-global-variable)